# C# command prompt commands not found

Tags: c#, command-line

I am trying to call tpmvscmgr.exe located in C:\Windows\System32
from my c# application.
I found this code:

```
       string strCmdText;
       strCmdText = @"/C Robocopy C:\Users\Johannes\test1 C:\Users\Johannes\test2";         
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe", strCmdText);
```

here [Run Command Prompt Commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands)
and it works good.

However when I try to change it to

```
  strCmdText = "/C Tpmvscmgr.exe create /name tpmvsc /pin default /adminkey random /generate ";
```

This does not work.
In fact when I debug and look around in the command prompt opened by the code I can not find the tpmvscmgr.exe in windows/system32.
Im guessing it is opened as a different user or with other priviledges or something but can this be fixed?
I really would need to run a tpmvscmgr.exe command from code.

Comment: What version of windows are you running? upwards from win 8? https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn593707(v=ws.11).aspx

Comment: windows 10. If I open a command prompt normally the exe is there. Just not in the command prompt opened from my code

Comment: In the command prompt you open normally, is it as an administrator or normal user?

Comment: While i dont have one of those in my windows\system32 area using any other exe in there I had no issues. What exactly are you having issues with?

Comment: I do not open it as administrator. The issue is that the command prompt I open from my code does not find the exe I want to run.(but it does exist)

Comment: You need to add to the process arguments for the options.

Comment: Hmm I do not understand, where and how would I go about doing that?
And just to make clear will this make the exe visible from the command line created from the code?

Answer (score 2):

OK I figured something out.
In my visual studio c# project I had "Any CPU" marked for the project. Apparently this means the console opens as win32.
When I changed the c# project to x86 I could run tpmvscmgr.exe
Pretty tricky stuff.

[C# cmd prompt cannot see telnet.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38383378/c-sharp-cmd-prompt-cannot-see-telnet-exe)